# Python: Discount program with if else in For loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have typed the following code, but the output is different from what I am expecting

```
n=int(input('enter number of items: '))
for i in range(n):
   cost=int(input('Please enter a item cost:'))
   if cost>=1000:    
     print('You have won a discount by 15 percent')
     cost*=0.85
   else:
     print('error')
print ('Now the total cost is ',cost)
```

This is the output that I am getting

```
enter number of items: 3
Please enter a item cost:500
You have won a discount by 5 percent
Please enter a item cost:900
You have won a discount by 5 percent
Please enter a item cost:1200
You have won a discount by 15 percent
Now the total cost is  1020.05
```

5% of only the last item is being calculated but not of all the other 2
Also, addition of the cost of the three items is not happening

I have just started learning python. How can I modify the code accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cost` is being reset on each loop and you aren't accumulating it (assuming that is what you want). If you just want to see the new discounted price you just need to indent the `print` statement.

Here are both changes:

```
total=0
n=int(input('enter number of items: '))
for i in range(n):
   cost=int(input('Please enter a item cost:'))
  if cost>=1000:    
    print('You have won a discount by 15 percent')
    cost*=0.85
    total+=cost
    print('new cost is ', cost)
  else:
    print('error')
print ('Now the total cost is ',total)
```

Answer (score 0):

One question, how are you inputting 500 and not getting error ?, you code should throw an error for giving values less than 1000, and you must have a variable named total, and add the values to the total, as you progress, and your code some editing because the output you showed here is not possible for 500, as it will show error

```py
total = 0
for i in range():
    cost = ...
    total += cost
print(total)
```